# The getbalance command shows an empty balance

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, bitcoind, unconfirmed-transactions

I sent bitcoins to an address and blockcypher says the transaction is done but as I try to learn the balance using  `bitcoin-cli -testnet getbalance <address>`, the address hasn't received yet. So why can't the address receive bitcoins even now?

I really don't know why I can't get bitcoins.

Obviously, as blockcypher says I sent some bitcoins to the address from other my address and blockcypher says that the transactions were confirmed.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear, so in brief, I want to send bitcoins successfully

Comment: It is still unclear for me. Please read https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I see. sorry I've read.
 so I sent bitcoins to an address and blockcypher says the transaction has done but as I try to know the balance using  `bitcoin-cli -testnet getbalance the address`, the address hasn't received yet.So why can't the address receive bitcoins even now?

Comment: I've edited your question to include the relevant information from the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can query the balance only of address you own.**

> I sent bitcoins to an address and blockcypher says the transaction has
>   done but as I try to know the balance using `bitcoin-cli -testnet getbalance the address`, the address hasn't received yet.So why
>   couldn't the address receive bitcoins or couldn't I send ?

The [`getbalance`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getbalance) RPC method(and related `bitcoin-cli` command) accept two arguments, first is a string and it isn't an address, it's an account name, second is a confirmation coint To get the balance of whole wallet use:

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet getbalance
```

Or use [`getreceivedbyaddress`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getreceivedbyaddress):

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet getreceivedbyaddress 'the address' 0
```

Comment: `$  bitcoin-cli -testnet getreceivedbyaddress mq7A3EUXa4eu3XUJeB2RjXyS75EzSkz4T2 0
=> 0.00000000`
it even says that the adress has nothing

Comment: Is your bitcoind fully synced? what the output of `getinfo` command? Also is this address owned by wallet of your bitcoind ?

Comment: It was synced completely.Thank you, I just found that the address wasn't valid so that I couldn't make my wallet have the address then it said the address has nothing.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you are passing the account name as first parameter. If no account name is passed it will show you the balance of all the address in that wallet